# What does this ${@:2} mean in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I see this in a shell script.

```
variable=${@:2}
```

What is it doing?

Comment: Is that exactly how it showed in the script? The syntax looks like an array but is missing some pieces. Can you please post a couple of the lines around this line from the script?

Comment: That is a variable starting from the second letter. `var="my_value"; echo var="${var[@]:2}"; echo "$var"` See the difference?

Answer (score 61):

It's showing the contents of the special variable `$@`, in Bash. It contains all the command line arguments, and this command is taking all the arguments from the second one on and storing them in a variable, `variable`.

#### Example

Here's an exampe script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${@:2}

variable=${@:3}
echo $variable
```

Example run:

```
./ex.bash 1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
```

#### References

- [Positional Parameters - Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF)

Comment: Note that the technique shown mashes the given arguments into a single string. If you need to keep them as separate arguments, use an array: `vars=( "${@:2}" )`

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also note the use of the curly brackets. You are supposed to always use curly brackets, but Bash allows you to omit them when the context is unambiguous. Therefore, `$@` and `${@}` are identical, although the latter is the "more correct" syntax. You have to use the brackets with `${@:2}`, because `$@:2` is ambiguous and would therefore be interpreted as `${@}:2`, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 18):

That's a `ksh` feature also found in `bash` and recent versions of `zsh`.

In `ksh` and `bash`, you can access several elements of an array by using the `${array[@]:first:length}` syntax, which expands to up to `length` (or all if `length` is omitted) elements of the `array` array (in the list of elements of the array sorted numerically on the indexes), starting with the first one with index greater or equal to `first`. When in scalar context (like here in an assignment to a scalar variable) the list of elements is joined with space characters with `bash` and `ksh93` and with the first character of `$IFS` (or nothing if `$IFS` is empty or space if it is unset) with `zsh`.

For instance:

```
$ a[23]=a a[5]=b a[235]=c a[45]=d
$ x=${a[@]:12:2}; printf '<%s>\n' "$x"
<a d>
```

`$@` is a special case. `$@` is the array of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...). But when used with `:`, `$0` is also included. So `${@:1}` is the same as `$@`, not `${@:0}` like for other arrays.

In `zsh`, it's slightly different. `zsh` added the `ksh` syntax only recently for compatibility but has its own syntax for selecting ranges of elements.

Contrary to `ksh` and `bash`, `zsh` arrays are a different variable type from scalar variables, are not sparse (`zsh` has associative arrays as another variable type) and start at index 1 instead of 0.

For `zsh`, you access array element ranges with `$a[first,last]` (where `last` can also be negative to count backwards from the end).

In `zsh`,

```
a[23]=a a[5]=b a[235]=c a[45]=d
```

creates an array with 235 elements, most of them empty. `$a[12,50]` would expand to elements 12 to 50, and `${a[@]:12:2}` would only expand to the (empty) `$a[12]` and `$a[13]` elements. As a special case, and again for portability with `ksh93` and `bash`, `zsh` also accepts a `0` first element for `$@` and treats that as `$0`.

So, you can use `${a[@]:x:n}` and `${@:x:n}` portably across all 3 shells, but only for non-sparse arrays, and pay attention to the value of IFS.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the array indexing syntax